# Wait/loading view while app makes API request

Tags: swift, rest, swiftui

I have a basic view named `QueryResult`.

```swift
struct QueryResult: View {

    var output: String { MakeDDGRequest(input: input) }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                Text("Result")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                Text(output)
                // Doesn't output anything because the function
                // returns earlier than the API request fetch
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have implemented a function call. (Just above the body definition.)

```swift
var output: String { MakeDDGRequest(input: input) }
```

The `input` variable is defined in the original code as a `@Binding public var input: String`

When I call this function (so when the view appears), I'd like to make an API request. I successfully did that, I got a JSON response and parsed it, but the function returns earlier than the API receives data, and so it doesn't return any data it fetched.

**How can I add a loading screen while this function is fetching data from the API?**

**Note** Please note that I am using **WatchOS**